# htaccess rewriterule with PHP $_GET methods in URL? (From sub-sub-folder to root dir)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, friendly-url

Currently I'm programming a small cms in which the "index.php" is loading the available templates and belonging contents from a database and manipulates the template with `str_replace`'s with the content. The usual URL looks like that:

```
http://URL/Dir1/template_hp/index.php?nav=content (*1)
```

As you see, I'm getting the Content-Names by `$_GET['nav']` dynamic. Now I'm trying to manipulate the URL with a .htaccess file placed in the root directory (`http://"URL"/".htaccess"`) to:

```
http://URL/cms/content
```

That if you call "`http://URL/cms`" the index.php without parameters will be shown as content (keep the clean URL) and if you call this URL with "`.../a_content_name`" the  "`.../index.php?nav=content`" will be shown (also keep the clean URL), but if you call the whole URL (*1) it will be shown as the cleaned once.

I've been looking and trying around for more than 15 hours by now and have done almost everything shown on web by any tutorials but all I get is either happens nothing or I get an **500 Internal Server Error** even with Mod_rewrite generator stuff.

What I've already done is that I `AllowOverride All` in the `apache2.conf`
and I always turn `RewriteEngine ON`, `php_flag display_errors on`,
`php_value error_reporting E_ALL` and `Options +FollowSymLinks`. What I wrote by myself was:

```
RewriteRule ^Dir1/template_hp/index.php?*.*(\?(.*)=(.*))$ cms?.*(/$1/$2) [NC,L]
```

...with about 9.000.000 different ways (escaping the "`.`" (or escaping the "`?`"), set RewriteBase to "`myURL`" and delete the "`^`" or just try the generated once from a webpage (`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /Dir1/template_hp/index.php?nav=$1 [L]`).

The only thing that worked was `RedirectMatch 301`, but that's just a small part of what I want:-(.

No one else here knows why it isn't working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /Dir1/template_hp/index\.php\?nav=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cms/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cms/(.+)/?$ /Dir1/template_hp/index.php?nav=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But now i have the Problem, that i need to call "my URL"/cms/"with a content name", and it is not showing my index.php at first without giving a content... Also the URL will not change to the "clear" "my URL"/cms/contentname format (which i'm giving with the GET)... The URL now looks like this: "my URL"/cms/content?nav=content (when i'm setting a content-name) or: "my URL"/cms/index.php?nav=content". I still don't get how to remove this? But im still very thankfull to you that it is at least showing the content!

Comment: @Y.Hermes If the rewrite is exactly as shown in `/cms/%1?`, it won't add the `nav=content` again after redirect. If you're using Apache 2.4 or later versions, you can use `[R=301,L,QSD]` flags.